# Problems installing flask on Debian server

Tags: python, ssl, pip, debian

I am having problems installing flask on my server.

```
$ sudo pip3 install flask
Collecting flask
From cffi callback <function _verify_callback at 0x7f2798df7840>:
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.5/dist-packages/OpenSSL/SSL.py", line 309, in wrapper
    _lib.X509_up_ref(x509)
AttributeError: module 'lib' has no attribute 'X509_up_ref'
  Could not find a version that satisfies the requirement flask (from versions: )
No matching distribution found for flask
```

I have upgraded and updated pip:

```
$ pip3 --version
pip 9.0.1 from /usr/lib/python3/dist-packages (python 3.5)
```

Debian version:

```
$ lsb_release -a
No LSB modules are available.
Distributor ID: Debian
Description:    Debian GNU/Linux 9.4 (stretch)
Release:    9.4
Codename:   stretch
```

Python version:

```
$ python3 --version
Python 3.5.3
```

I believe the main error is related to the lib module, as you can see on the error code, but I have no idea of how to solve it. I can `pip install` other packages, but get this error with `pip install flask`.

Comment: This looks like a certificate error... there is a version of 2.7 that gives the same error try 3.6 or 3.5.6 or something... you can also sudo apt-get uninstall python-pip. And try reinstalling with easy_install

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/search?q=%5Bpip%5D+AttributeError%3A+module+%27lib%27+has+no+attribute+%27X509_up_ref%27